# How to repeat same animation while working with CABasicAnimation

Tags: swift, repeat, cabasicanimation

I am creating my own custom activity indicator. I created a circular view with CAShapeLayer and I managed to stroke the circular layer but I want to do it indefinitely until the user wants to stop. The following is my stroke layer animation code.

```
private func getStrokeEndAnimation()->CABasicAnimation{
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.fromValue = 0.0
        animation.toValue = 1.0
        animation.duration = 2.0
        animation.fillMode = .forwards
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        return animation
}
```

There is an instance property on BasicAnimation named `repeatCount` but if I specify that my activity indicator will animate the given number of times like  if I do

```
animation.repeatCount = 3
```

it will animate only 3 times. How can I make sure that the animation keeps going indefinitely until, I stop it.

Comment: It's right there in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/camediatiming/1427666-repeatcount)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`animation.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude` will for all practical purposes repeat it forever.

Comment: Thank you, don't know how I missed it. However just for curiosity when should I use .greatestFiniteMagnitude and when should I use .infinity

Comment: please read out apple docs ...it said `This value compares greater than or equal to all finite numbers, but less than infinity.
This value corresponds to type-specific C macros such as FLT_MAX and DBL_MAX. The naming of those macros is slightly misleading, because infinity is greater than this value.`

Comment: here is the link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/1849607-greatestfinitemagnitude

Comment: so using .infinity is not misleading :) ... it actually simply shows what you meant

Comment: To be honest it never occurred to me to use .infinity till seeing the other answers and the duplicate, every day is a school day!

Answer (score 1):

You can use infinity in repeat count according to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint/1641304-infinity)

> Infinity compares greater than all finite numbers and equal to other
> infinite values.

```
animation.repeatCount = .infinity
```